# how to compute multiple variables using loop

Tags: loops

In the dataset, there are two columns "start_year" and "end_year", indicating the year a patient start and end the registration in the GP clinic. I want to know whether each patient was registered in the clinic from 1990 to 2019. Probably compute 20 new variables (1=yes,0=no) for each year.

I used ifelse (R) to compute the variable one by one:

```
test$pt_1990<-ifelse(test$start_year<=1990 & 1990<=test$end_year,1,0)
```

Hope loops could have a better solution instead of write 20 lines of same code. Thank u very much

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What programming language is this? Please tag the appropriate language.